# How to prevent wso2 from asking for contacts email addresses

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How do i remove the `scope=wl.contacts_emails` (in the url) when being redirected to the microsoft(hotmail, msn, live) login page.

It seems by default wso2 want windows live clients contacts email addresses. Obviously i have no need for this info.

Please note i have no claims set on this federation authenticator, so it seems to be hard coded

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in the current version 5.0.0

A custom authenticator needs to be created.